# How to Posting Form Data from android?

Tags: java, android, http, browser

I want to use Android java "emulate" a browser and post Login data. I tried this [How to submit HTML form data (method=POST) using JAVA](http://alien.dowling.edu/~vassil/tutorials/javapost.php)
But I failed.....

url:http://192.168.254.34/Control?id=1000

Here are the html source:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312">
<title>欢迎使用WLAN无线宽带</title>
<style><!--
a {text-decoration: none}
.f1 { font-size: 10.5pt; font-family: Verdana; line-height: 12pt }
.f2 { font-size: 8pt; font-family: Verdana; line-height: 12pt }
.btn {
 BORDER-LEFT: #7b9ebd 1px solid;
 BORDER-RIGHT: #7b9ebd 1px solid;
 BORDER-TOP: #7b9ebd 1px solid;
 BORDER-BOTTOM: #7b9ebd 1px solid;
 PADDING-LEFT: 2px;
 PADDING-RIGHT: 2px;
 PADDING-TOP: 2px;
 FONT-SIZE: 10.5pt;
 CURSOR: hand;
 COLOR: black;
 FILTER: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr=#ffffff, EndColorStr=#cecfde);
}
-->
</style>
<base href="http://192.168.254.34/pageset/131/PDA/"> 
</head><body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
                <!-- 本地动态密码开始-->
                <script>
                    function submitform2(){
                       if (form1.strAccount.value==""){
                           alert("请填入用户名!");
                           return;
                       }
                       form2.num.value=form1.strAccount.value;
                       form2.submit();
                    }
                </script>
                <iframe scr="about:blank" width="0" height="0" name="a"></iframe>
              <FORM name="form2" method=post action="http://218.204.223.213:8080/cmpp/service.do?id=newuser" target="a">
                    <input size=12 type=hidden  name="num" maxlength=26 style="border:1px solid #999999; FONT-SIZE: 10.5pt; BACKGROUND: #ffffff; COLOR: #333399; FONT-FAMILY: verdana; 1px:" size="14"></td>
                    <INPUT value="172.31.18.199" type=hidden name=ip>
                </FORM> 

            <!-- 本地动态密码结束 --><form name=form1 method=post action="/Control?id=2000">

<center>
<table width=600 border=0 height=800>
  <tr>
    <td height=800>
  <div align=center>
    <center>
  <table width=600 border=0 height=800 bgcolor=#FFFFFF cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor=#111111>
    <tr>
        <td height=800 width=600 background="a02.jpg" align="center">
        <table border="0" width="288" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="97%">
            <tr>
                <td height="82" colspan="2">
                <p align="center" class="f1">
                　</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="295" align="center" colspan="2">
                <table border="0" width="104%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="106%">
                    <tr>
                        <td height="148" colspan="2">
                        <p align="center">
                        <font color="#333399" style="font-size: 10.5pt">
                        欢迎使用WLAN无线登陆页面</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="32%" height="33" align="right" class="f1">
                        用户帐号</td>
                        <td height="33" width="68%">
                        &nbsp;<input name=strAccount maxlength=26 style="border:1px solid #999999; FONT-SIZE: 10.5pt; BACKGROUND: #ffffff; COLOR: #333399; FONT-FAMILY: verdana; 1px:" size="21"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="32%" align="right" class="f1">用户密码</td>
                        <td width="68%">
                        &nbsp;<input type=password name=strPassword maxlength=16 style="border:1px solid #999999; FONT-SIZE: 10.5pt; BACKGROUND: #ffffff; COLOR: #333399; FONT-FAMILY: verdana; 1px:"         size="21"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="96" colspan="2" align="left">
                        <p align="center">
                    &nbsp;<input type="button" value="登 录" width="86" height="23" name="I1" onclick="javascript:form1.submit();"  class="btn">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="reset" value="重 置" width="86" height="23" name="I2" class="btn"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="f1" width="255">
                <p align="center">　</td>
                <td class="f1" width="33">
                　</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="f1" height="91" width="255">
                <p align="center" class="f1">
                　</td>
                <td class="f1" height="91" width="33">
                　</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="108" colspan="2">
                <p align="center">
                &nbsp;<br>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table></center></div></td></tr></table></center></form></body></html>
```

the header I get:(use  chrome)

```
Request URL:http://192.168.254.34/Control?id=2000
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:28
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:JSESSIONID=45129DDCC372B780F65344DB9DB107FB
Host:192.168.254.34
Origin:http://192.168.254.34
Referer:http://192.168.254.34/Control?id=1000
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko)               Chrome/13.0.782.107 Safari/535.1
Query String Parametersview URL encoded
id:2000
Form Dataview URL encoded
strAccount:username
strPassword:password
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:2202
Content-Type:text/html;charset=GBK
Date:Mon, 08 Aug 2011 11:04:25 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma:No-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie:intPageSetID=131; Expires=Mon, 08-Aug-2011 11:04:55 GMT
```

anybody know how to post login data?????????

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit form with POST data in Android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999945/submit-form-with-post-data-in-android-app)

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I do it:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("www.server.com/dologin.php");

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "KennyStarfighter");
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "SecretPassword");
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect", "?controller=login&view=loggedonpage"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity he = response.getEntity();
```

Then I can for instance handle the response as XML.

```
xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(he.getContent()));
```

Comment: @user883883 - You'll need the correct names of the login fields on the webpage for your POST-command. The names in my example were arbitrary. Also, depending on your implementation, you may not need to log in. It all depends on what you want to perform.

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpClient.  I can do the post and handle authentication.  Doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html)